# Why is the stubbed method not called?

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, stub

It seems I understood something wrong. I have a class

```
module Spree
  class OmnikassaPaymentResponse
    #...
    # Finds a payment with provided parameters trough ActiveRecord.
    def payment(state = :processing)
      Spree::Payment.find(:first, :conditions => { :amount => @amount, :order_id => @order_id, :state => state } ) || raise(ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound)
    end
  end
end
```

Which is specced in Rspec:

```
describe "#payment" do
  it 'should try to find a Spree::Payment' do
    Spree::Payment.any_instance.stub(:find).and_return(Spree::Payment.new)
    Spree::Payment.any_instance.should_receive(:find)
    Spree::OmnikassaPaymentResponse.new(@seal, @data).payment
  end
end
```

This, however, always throws `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`. I expected `any_instance.stub(:find).and_return()` to make sure that whenever, wherever I call a `#find` on whatever instance I happen to have of Spree::Payment, it returns something.

In other words: I would expect the `stub.and_return` would avoid getting to `|| raise(ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound)`. But it does not.

Is my assumption wrong, my code? Something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case `find` is not an instance method, but a class method of `Spree::Payment`. That means you should stub it directly without `any_instance` like that:

```
Spree::Payment.stub(:find).and_return(Spree::Payment.new)
```

Comment: Thanks! FWIW: also the `.should_receive(:find)` must be called without the `any_instance`.